# Applying jQuery UI buttonset

Tags: jquery, user-interface

http://jsfiddle.net/TurtleWolf/625eC/

I am missing something on the radio button set. I've gotten it to work on a previous version, but I'm missing something this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working.  There's just no stylesheet.  If you use firebug or some other web inspector you can see that jquery-ui has applied its classes and events to the radio buttons.

Comment: +1 for noticing the problem--I don't know why jsFiddle doesn't make it easier to add a UI stylesheet since they make it so easy to add UI. And the CSS/resource stuff is tucked away in the left menu--heard to notice.

Comment: @JAAulde +1 as soon as I can vote, for rebuilding my fiddle. I have saved it as the new base. So would anyone have the time to diagnose the same issue via http://turtlewolf.info ...

Comment: @TurtleWolf - no problem.  On your live site, the issue is that neither jQuery UI nor its style sheet are being loaded on your page. The URLs you point to for each result in a 404 (http://turtlewolf.info/js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js and http://turtlewolf.info/css/themename/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css )

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded my ui css file as a resource to http://jsfiddle.net/625eC/6/

numbers1311407 was correct, there was no problem in your markup. Just no css file included.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you need to add a style sheet.

Using the [Google CDN hosted version of the 'base' jQuery 1.8.9 stylesheet](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) (because you're using UI 1.8.9 in the fiddle), I ***[updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/625eC/5/)*** by clicking "add resources" in the left menu (switches to "manage resources" once you have one or more loaded) and pasting the stylesheet URL.